# Git bugtraq for all users who clone my repos?

Tags: git, bug-tracking

I'm used to svn to use `svn:propset` to set bugtraq URLs, pus`^H^H^H`commit them to the server and all users who clo`^H^H^H`checkout from it have the settings.

In git I can store them in my local or repository specific configuration, but other users who clone from it don't benefit from it: they simply don't get my bugtraq configuration.

Do I need to educate every users to configure their checkouts (also unsatisfying when I move somewhere else have to do clone my repository again) or it possible to feed it when the repository is being cloned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Chacon on his excellent [ProGit](http://git-scm.com/book) book's blog posted information about [git notes](http://git-scm.com/2010/08/25/notes.html).

Do be aware that you will need to tell everyone to pull all references, they will need to add this to their git config for that repository.

---

Git notes allow one to add a note to an existing commit without modifying the commit message it self. This can for instance be used to locally add information to a certain commit.

Notes however are only considered local and are not automatically pushed/pulled from a remote server, and if two people edit the same note conflicts happen much like with regular commits and they require fixing by checking out the notes head and manually fixing things up.

This makes using notes more difficult, and unfortunately it doesn't seem like this has been improved much in newer versions of git.

Comment: How does this relate to sharing repository config?

Comment: @Borek: You decided to down-vote and comment on a post that was made in 2011, almost a year ago, which was accepted by the original author. If this answer wasn't specific to your situation you are more than welcome to create a new question on which you will receive answers for your specific situation, in this case my answer was satisfactory to the original authors intent and helped him solve his issue of sharing bugtraq ID's.

Comment: I have downvoted because I haven't found the answer useful - that's what downvotes are for. Maybe I am just missing something so I have added a comment (question) and you have an opportunity to explain that this was indeed a useful answer.

Comment: This is a useful answer because it allows sharing of the bugtraq ID's like the original author requested. The original author marked this answer as accepted. You come along a year later and downvote the answer because it doesn't answer your specific needs, as I mentioned before, ask your own question and get answers tailored to your need... I honestly don't care so much about the down-vote, I've got plenty to spare, just don't understand why.

Comment: No point in arguing about voting but let me ask again about the very essence of the question and your answer - I want to synchronize bugtraq configuration (not sure what you mean by "bugtraq IDs") between clones. How do git notes help with this? Should I store the bugtraq config section in a note? How to ensure that when someone clones the repo, the config section will go from the note to the `.git/config` file? Or did you have something completely different in mind? No point for me to create a new question because this one asks exactly what I'm after, I just don't understand the answer.

Comment: @Borek I think it was the OP who had something completely different in mind. Anyway, I have the same problem as you. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't understand this answer and the link is broken. Can someone explain what he means? How do you commit your bugtraq settings in .git/config?  What is 'pull all references'?

Comment: This won't allow you to commit your bugtraq settings in your .git/config, this will allow you to add a note to a commit to add bugtraq information to a commit after the fact.

This workflow is not well supported with git, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

There has been something started now: https://github.com/mstrap/bugtraq

Comment: SmartGit uses this, and it's very nice. I wish more Git clients would integrate this; it's a very lightweight and flexible solution.